# How to avoid Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.UpdateRegionsException

Tags: prism

I am getting this exception only first time when I am trying to access the region.

```
  var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
  IRegion region = regionManager.Regions[Regions.DevicePropertiesRegion];
```

Exception only comes first time here. Second time it works fine. Also if I hit this point with debug and wait for a while it works first time also. Looks like some updation is going on background. Any idea how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: When and where is this code being executed?

Comment: I am using PRISM, I have a method in some viewmodel where this code is written and that method is subscribe to the event.